# Is it possible to use a 12V 3,35A power supply to power a 20V 2,5A device?

Tags: power-supply, adapter

title says it all.. The device works with that power supply (adapter), but will it make any damage to the device or even worse (blow out or something like that)?

thanks

Comment: Based on the available information there's no way to say for sure.

Comment: "The device works with that power supply" Most people would ask first and try later.

Comment: What is the device?

Comment: @Dampmaskin what other information do you need to tell me more?

Comment: @SteveG it is a small label printer

Comment: @Oldfart I just tried it turn it on and off for couple of seconds

Comment: It could work depending on how much current your device draws.. If it draws more than 2.5A, which is your specified limit, then the power supply power may take over and blow up your device.

Comment: @12Lappie there is a label on the device that says 20V and 2,5A..

Comment: input power 12Vx3.35A = 40.2W and the output power 20Vx2.5A=50W As toy can see you can't get 2.5A at 20V but you can get around 40W/20V =2A (less than that). But you need a step-up (boost) converter.

Comment: Try to Google "DC-DC Step-up Boost Converter module"

Comment: Did you successfully print a label using that power supply? If not, then saying "the device works" is probably an overstatement.

Answer (score 0):

A 12 volt power supply capable of providing 3.35 amps can deliver a power of 40.2 watts (assumed continuously). A load that takes 2.5 amps from a 20 volt supply requires a power of 50 watts.

Therefore a 40.2 watt power supply will never be able to continuously deliver the power required by a device that wants to consume 50 watts.

> The device works with that power supply (adapter)

Then it isn't consuming 50 watts when you determined it worked.

> but will it make any damage to the device or even worse (blow out or
>   something like that)?

It all depends on the circuitry details for power supply and device.